# Value not update in one2many field with compute method Odoo12

Tags: odoo, insert-update, odoo-12, one2many

My below method for value insertion in one2many field works with the onchange method and the compute method with depends decorator. But my requirement not full-fill with depends decorator. My method should work with view load. At present method calls, and I tested it with print on the terminal but still value not updated in o2many field.

```
survey_user_input = fields.One2many('customer.survey', 'partner_id', compute='user_survey_output')

@api.one
def user_survey_output(self):
    print('TESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS')
    Survey_user_input = self.env['survey.user_input']
    s_list = []
    value = {}
    for val in self:
        User_input = Survey_user_input.search(['|', ('partner_id', '=', val.id), ('email', '=', val.email)])
        for rec in User_input:
            data = {'partner_id': val.id,
                    'user_input_id': rec.id,
                    'survey_id': rec.survey_id.id,
                    'date_create': rec.date_create,
                    'deadline': rec.deadline,
                    'type': rec.type,
                    'state': rec.state,
                    }
            s_list.append((0, 0, data))
        value.update(survey_user_input=s_list)
        print('LLLLLLLLLLLLLLL', value)
        return {'value': value}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which model you have created the **survey_user_input** field?
You prepared dictionary dynamic and return it but where it is used?

Comment: in 'res.partner' model i created survey_user_input field.

Answer (score 2):

`survey_user_input` is a [computed field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields), so it must assign the computed value to the field.

If it uses the values of other fields, it should specify those fields using `depends()`(The `email` field is used in the `search` method).

```
@api.depends('email')
def user_survey_output(self):
    Survey_user_input = self.env['survey.user_input']
    for val in self:
        s_list = []
        # Loop body used to fill "s_list"
        val.survey_user_input = s_list
```

Comment: I used email in depends but still it not updating field automatically on search.

Comment: I am using one2many field in 'res.partner' model and co_model is 'survey.survey'. I want to update this field when changes occurs in survey models. So, depends decorator not used in my case.

Comment: Do you have any field related to the survey?

Comment: partner_id or id field

Comment: Can you please update your question and add the fields?

Comment: Hello Kenly, my problem solved by run my method on survey create and write method. Thanks for your help.